# How to use different buckets in GCS python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have:

```py
bucket_name = os.environ.get(
            'mosaictest', app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
```

But It would always show the default gcs bucket(for me it is "{project id}.appspot.com" instead of 'mosaictest'(I created this bucket) how do I use the "mosaictest' bucket?

Answer (score 1):

I am an idiot
just write: bucket_name={literally name the bucket you want to use lol}

Comment: If your question has no great value ... might you want to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code retrieves the value of an environment variable called `mosaictest` and uses the value of that variable.  If the variable is not set, then you will get the default value as returned from the `get_default_gcs_bucket_name()` function call.  If you are finding that you are getting the default value then it is likely your environment variable is not set.  You didn't specify how you might have been setting it in your original post.  In Linux, you would do something like:

```
export mosaictest=MYVALUE
python myapp.py
```